# Fetching content from html and write fetched content in a specific format in CSV

Tags: python, csv, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have HTML Code like:

```
<!-- Snippet snippets/search_result_text.html end -->
</h2>





      <p class="filter-list">


          <span class="facet">Organisations:</span>

            <span class="filtered pill">**Reserve Bank of Australia**
              <a href="/dataset?groups=business" class="remove" title="Remove"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
            </span>



          <span class="facet">Groups:</span>

            <span class="filtered pill">**Business Support and Regulation**
              <a href="/dataset?organization=reservebankofaustralia" class="remove" title="Remove"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
            </span>


      </p>



</form>




<!-- Snippet snippets/search_form.html end -->




<!-- Snippet snippets/search_package_list.html start -->



        <ul class="dataset-list unstyled">






<!-- Snippet snippets/package_item.html start -->






<li class="dataset-item">

    <div class="dataset-content">
      <h3 class="dataset-heading">



        <a href="/dataset/banks-assets">**Banks – Assets**</a>




      </h3>


        <div>These data are derived from returns submitted to the Australian Prudential Regulation Authority (APRA) by banks authorised under the Banking Act 1959. APRA assumed...</div>

    </div>

      <ul class="dataset-resources unstyled">

          <li>

            <a href="/dataset/banks-assets" class="label" data-format="xls">XLS</a>

          </li>

      </ul>


</li>
<!-- Snippet snippets/package_item.html end -->





<!-- Snippet snippets/package_item.html start -->






<li class="dataset-item">

    <div class="dataset-content">
      <h3 class="dataset-heading">



        <a href="/dataset/consolidated-exposures-immediate-and-ultimate-risk-basis">**Consolidated Exposures – Immediate and Ultimate Risk Basis**</a>




      </h3>


        <div>In March 2003, banks and selected Registered Financial Corporations (RFCs) began reporting their international assets, liabilities and country exposures to APRA in ARF/RRF 231...</div>

    </div>

      <ul class="dataset-resources unstyled">

          <li>

            <a href="/dataset/consolidated-exposures-immediate-and-ultimate-risk-basis" class="label" data-format="xls">XLS</a>

          </li>

      </ul>


</li>
<!-- Snippet snippets/package_item.html end -->
```

I want to extract data which is in bold letters above and the want to write in csv specific format like:

```
Group                               Organisation              Title              
Business Support and Regulation    Reserve Bank of Australia   Banks-Assets
Business Support and Regulation    Reserve Bank of Australia   Consolidated Exposures – Immediate and Ultimate Risk Basis
```

and so on....
I have my python code which gives two different files.

```
webpage_urls = ["https://data.gov.au/dataset?q=&groups=business&sort=extras_harvest_portal+asc%2C+score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc&_organization_limit=0&organization=reservebankofaustralia&_groups_limit=0",
                "https://data.gov.au/dataset?q=&groups=business&sort=extras_harvest_portal+asc%2C+score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc&_organization_limit=0&organization=department-of-finance&_groups_limit=0",
                "https://data.gov.au/dataset?q=&groups=business&sort=extras_harvest_portal+asc%2C+score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc&_organization_limit=0&organization=departmentofagriculturefisheriesandforestry&_groups_limit=0",
                "https://data.gov.au/dataset?organization=department-of-communications&q=&groups=business&sort=extras_harvest_portal+asc%2C+score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc&_organization_limit=0&_groups_limit=0",
                "https://data.gov.au/dataset?organization=ip-australia&q=&groups=business&sort=extras_harvest_portal+asc%2C+score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc&_organization_limit=0&_groups_limit=0",
                "https://data.gov.au/dataset?q=&organization=australiancommunicationsandmediaauthority&groups=business&sort=extras_harvest_portal+asc%2C+score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc&_organization_limit=0&_groups_limit=0",
                "https://data.gov.au/dataset?q=&organization=www-mitchellshirecouncil-vic-gov-au&groups=business&sort=extras_harvest_portal+asc%2C+score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc&_organization_limit=0&_groups_limit=0",
                "https://data.gov.au/dataset?q=&groups=business&sort=extras_harvest_portal+asc%2C+score+desc%2C+metadata_modified+desc&_organization_limit=0&organization=digital-transformation-agency&_groups_limit=0"]
# fetching data from all urls
data = []
dfs = []

for i in webpage_urls:
    wiki2 = i
    page= urllib.request.urlopen(wiki2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

    lobbying = {}
    data2 = soup.find_all('h3', class_="dataset-heading")
    for element in data2:
        lobbying[element.a.get_text()] = {}
    data2[0].a["href"]
    prefix = "https://data.gov.au"
    for element in data2:
        print()
        lobbying[element.a.get_text()]["link"] = prefix + element.a["href"]
        #print(lobbying)
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(lobbying, orient='index').rename_axis('Titles').reset_index()
        dfs.append(df)
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset = 'Titles')
print (df1)
df1.to_csv('D:/output2.csv')

for i in webpage_urls:
    wiki2 = i
    page= urllib.request.urlopen(wiki2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

    # fetching organisations
    data3 = soup.find_all('li', class_="nav-item active")
    lobbying1 = []
    for element in data3:
        lobbying1.append(element.span.get_text())
        data.append(lobbying1)



df_ = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Organisations', 'Groups'])
df2 = df_.drop_duplicates(subset = 'Organisations')
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', 999):
    print (df2)
df2.to_csv('D:/output_new.csv')
```

above one is giving link also. Please help in in getting desired format in single csv with three columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try a bit modify original solution - best is loop only once and create one big `DataFrame` with all data. then only select columns with subset `[['col1','col2']` for new `DataFrames`.

Also for remove numbers with `()` is possible use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
for i in webpage_urls:
    wiki2 = i
    page= urllib.request.urlopen(wiki2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

    lobbying = {}
    #always only 2 active li, so select first by [0]  and second by [1]
    org = soup.find_all('li', class_="nav-item active")[0].span.get_text()
    groups = soup.find_all('li', class_="nav-item active")[1].span.get_text()

    data2 = soup.find_all('h3', class_="dataset-heading")
    for element in data2:
        lobbying[element.a.get_text()] = {}
    data2[0].a["href"]
    prefix = "https://data.gov.au"
    for element in data2:
        lobbying[element.a.get_text()]["link"] = prefix + element.a["href"]
        lobbying[element.a.get_text()]["Organisation"] = org
        lobbying[element.a.get_text()]["Group"] = groups
        #print(lobbying)
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(lobbying, orient='index') \
               .rename_axis('Titles').reset_index()
        dfs.append(df)
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset = 'Titles').reset_index(drop=True)



df1['Organisation'] = df1['Organisation'].str.replace('\(\d+\)', '')
df1['Group'] = df1['Group'].str.replace('\(\d+\)', '')
```

---

```
print (df1.head())
                                              Titles             Organisation  \
0                                     Banks – Assets  Reserve Bank of Aus...    
1  Consolidated Exposures – Immediate and Ultimat...  Reserve Bank of Aus...    
2  Foreign Exchange Transactions and Holdings of ...  Reserve Bank of Aus...    
3  Finance Companies and General Financiers – Sel...  Reserve Bank of Aus...    
4                   Liabilities and Assets – Monthly  Reserve Bank of Aus...    

                                                link                    Group  
0           https://data.gov.au/dataset/banks-assets  Business Support an...   
1  https://data.gov.au/dataset/consolidated-expos...  Business Support an...   
2  https://data.gov.au/dataset/foreign-exchange-t...  Business Support an...   
3  https://data.gov.au/dataset/finance-companies-...  Business Support an...   
4  https://data.gov.au/dataset/liabilities-and-as...  Business Support an...
```

---

```
df2 = df1[['Titles', 'link']]
print (df2.head())
                                              Titles  \
0                                     Banks – Assets   
1  Consolidated Exposures – Immediate and Ultimat...   
2  Foreign Exchange Transactions and Holdings of ...   
3  Finance Companies and General Financiers – Sel...   
4                   Liabilities and Assets – Monthly   

                                                link  
0           https://data.gov.au/dataset/banks-assets  
1  https://data.gov.au/dataset/consolidated-expos...  
2  https://data.gov.au/dataset/foreign-exchange-t...  
3  https://data.gov.au/dataset/finance-companies-...  
4  https://data.gov.au/dataset/liabilities-and-as...
```

---

```
df3 = df1[['Group','Organisation','Titles']]
print (df3.head())
                     Group             Organisation  \
0  Business Support an...   Reserve Bank of Aus...    
1  Business Support an...   Reserve Bank of Aus...    
2  Business Support an...   Reserve Bank of Aus...    
3  Business Support an...   Reserve Bank of Aus...    
4  Business Support an...   Reserve Bank of Aus...    

                                              Titles  
0                                     Banks – Assets  
1  Consolidated Exposures – Immediate and Ultimat...  
2  Foreign Exchange Transactions and Holdings of ...  
3  Finance Companies and General Financiers – Sel...  
4                   Liabilities and Assets – Monthly
```

Comment: thanks alot for refining code. Its is giving finally what I wanted.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is hard for me, so maybe some better solution can be. But I think main idea is loop only if necessary, because it is very slow operiation.

Comment: okay, yeah looping was the problem. I am looping many URLs and it has taken around 1 hour and still running. So yeah that is slow in python.

Comment: the output that I am getting is Business Support an... and Reserve Bank of Aus...., right, I want to print the whole text not "......." for all. I replaced line 9 and 10 as "org = soup.find_all('a', {'class':'nav-item active'})[0].get('title')" & "groups = soup.find_all('a', {'class':'nav-item active'})[1].get('title')" in above code. And I am running it separately and getting error: list index out of range. What should I use to extract complete sentences?

Comment: @Arti123 - Can you create new question? I find answer but it was a bit complicated. In my opinion you can use your comment as main text and also you can add link to this question. thanks.

Comment: sure jezrael, I am creating new question.

Comment: I tried with another method too, but getting complete column of same organisations and groups, you have any way out?I posted question separately.

Comment: okay, thanks to you too, glad to know you solved it. please upload your answer.

Comment: @Arti123 - Can you create new question? Because the best for each problem is add new answer, no edit old one. thanks.

Comment: @ jezrael, I created the time I saw your comment. Here is a link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44964419/get-title-inside-link-tag-in-html-using-beautifulsoup/44964690#44964690, please have a look. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I think you get pandas tag. I add answer.

Comment: @jerael, ohh okay :), yeah I did not write pandas.