# get title inside link tag in HTML using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am extracting data from https://data.gov.au/dataset?organization=reservebankofaustralia&_groups_limit=0&groups=business 
and got output I wanted but now problem is: the output that I am getting is Business Support an... and Reserve Bank of Aus...., not complete text, I want to print the whole text not "......." for all. I replaced line 9 and 10 in answer by jezrael, please refer to [Fetching content from html and write fetched content in a specific format in CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44941796/fetching-content-from-html-and-write-fetched-content-in-a-specific-format-in-csv/44942641?noredirect=1#comment76902375_44942641) with code 
`org = soup.find_all('a', {'class':'nav-item active'})[0].get('title') 
groups = soup.find_all('a', {'class':'nav-item active'})[1].get('title')`
. And I am running it separately and getting error: list index out of range. What should I use to extract complete sentences? I also tried :
`org = soup.find_all('span',class_="filtered pill")`, it gave answer of type string when I ran separately but could not run with whole code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All data with longer text are in attribut `title`, shorter are in text. So add double `if`:

```
for i in webpage_urls:
    wiki2 = i
    page= urllib.request.urlopen(wiki2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

    lobbying = {}
    #always only 2 active li, so select first by [0]  and second by [1]
    l = soup.find_all('li', class_="nav-item active")

    org = l[0].a.get('title')
    if org == '':
        org = l[0].span.get_text()

    groups = l[1].a.get('title')
    if groups == '':
        groups = l[1].span.get_text()

    data2 = soup.find_all('h3', class_="dataset-heading")
    for element in data2:
        lobbying[element.a.get_text()] = {}
    data2[0].a["href"]
    prefix = "https://data.gov.au"
    for element in data2:
        lobbying[element.a.get_text()]["link"] = prefix + element.a["href"]
        lobbying[element.a.get_text()]["Organisation"] = org
        lobbying[element.a.get_text()]["Group"] = groups

        #print(lobbying)
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(lobbying, orient='index') \
               .rename_axis('Titles').reset_index()
        dfs.append(df)
```

---

```
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset = 'Titles').reset_index(drop=True)

df1['Organisation'] = df1['Organisation'].str.replace('\(\d+\)', '')
df1['Group'] = df1['Group'].str.replace('\(\d+\)', '')
```

---

```
print (df1.head())

                                              Titles  \
0                                     Banks – Assets   
1  Consolidated Exposures – Immediate and Ultimat...   
2  Foreign Exchange Transactions and Holdings of ...   
3  Finance Companies and General Financiers – Sel...   
4                   Liabilities and Assets – Monthly   

                                                link  \
0           https://data.gov.au/dataset/banks-assets   
1  https://data.gov.au/dataset/consolidated-expos...   
2  https://data.gov.au/dataset/foreign-exchange-t...   
3  https://data.gov.au/dataset/finance-companies-...   
4  https://data.gov.au/dataset/liabilities-and-as...   

                Organisation                            Group  
0  Reserve Bank of Australia  Business Support and Regulation  
1  Reserve Bank of Australia  Business Support and Regulation  
2  Reserve Bank of Australia  Business Support and Regulation  
3  Reserve Bank of Australia  Business Support and Regulation  
4  Reserve Bank of Australia  Business Support and Regulation
```

Comment: thanks alot. can you please explain what this logic "if org == '': " is doing?

Comment: There is problem if check html some attributes title are empty, so need if. If omit it get no text.

Comment: @ jezrael, :), have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to do this. Here in each link there is title attribute. So here I simply checked if there is any title attribute present or not and if it is then I simply printed it.

There are blank lines because there are few links where `title=""` so you can avoid that using conditional statement and then get all titles from that.

```
>>> l = soup.find_all('a')
>>> for i in l:
...     if i.has_attr('title'):
...             print(i['title'])
... 
Remove
Remove
Reserve Bank of Australia

Business Support and Regulation













Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Australia
>>>
```

Comment: thanks, Its working for one URL, now I have run programs for all URLs. Let's see what will be output.

Comment: @ shashank, while running number of URLs, I am getting same thing. I think it should be loop in loop.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you trying to do ? I mean how you planning to go and fetch data

Comment: @ shashank, its done, thank you for catching. A link is given in my question, there is detail what I wanted to do.